# Web Worker not working

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I am a new to HTML5. I recently went through the basics of HTML5 but when I went to the intermediate level of coding with HTML5, I came up with a thing called "HTML5 Web Workers". I wrote a simple program using it but its not working.

**My HTML5 Code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 - Web Workers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Count : <output id="result"></output></p>
        <button onclick="startWorker()">Start count</button>
        <button onclick="endWorker()">End count</button>

        <script>
        var w; //the variable of object for web worker

        function startWorker() {
            if(typeof(Worker)!="undefined") //checking if browser supports web worker
            {
                if(typeof(w)=="undefined")
                {
                    w = new Worker("counter.js");
                }
                w.onmessage = function(e)
                {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.data;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your browser doesnot support HTML5 Web Worker! :)"; // or display the message that web worker is not supported!
            }
        }

        function endWorker() {
            w.terminate();
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My Web Worker File:**

```
var i=0;

function timedCount() {
    i=i+1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()", 500);
}

timedCount();
```

Can you tell me why it's not working?

Comment: Where's `postMessage()`? What exactly is not working and what do you expect to happen? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Juhana, postMessage() is a predefined function!

Comment: Ok. What exactly is not working and what do you expect to happen? Any errors in the console?

Comment: my code of javascript is not working, i expect it to start counting from 1 to infinite when the user clicks the "start worker" button until the user clicks the "stop worker" button!

Comment: Ok. Any errors in the console?

Comment: I didn't get it, I'm running it on the webpage.

Comment: The code looks fine so I am assuming it may not be detecting the counter.js file.  Try specifying the full path to the file:   w = new Worker("C:\FilePath\counter.js");

Comment: I mean the [JavaScript error console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console) on your browser.

Comment: still! not working! :/

Comment: Try alerting something after the web worker gets created and inspect the `w` variable to ensure it has been created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Which browser are you using and which error are you getting in the error console?

If you are using Chrome and are testing from the local filesystem (i.e. you have not uploaded your files to a web server), then you have to add a special flag when starting the browser. You have to start Chrome with `chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` which basically allows you to create workers from scripts on the local filesystem. But if you upload your files to a webserver and test using those files -- you won't need this flag.

Comment: I've solved this issue without this config with XAMPP local web server. Is local web server the answer and suitable solution ?

Comment: In my side, it is still not working even though it is very simple script,